# $f_n$ integrable and uniformly convergent on $[a,b]$ $\implies$ $f$ is integrable on $[a, b]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Claim: Let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions integrable on $[a, b]$ and $(f_n) \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $[a, b]$. Then $f$ is integrable on $[a, b]$.

I know that by the integrability of $f_n$, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a partition $P_\epsilon$ of $[a, b]$ such that for each $n\in\mathbb N$,
$$U(f_n, P_\epsilon) - L(f_n, P_\epsilon) < \epsilon$$
Also, by the uniform convergence of $(f_n)$ there exists an $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n\geq N$,
$$|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$$
So I want to show that: For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a partition $\mathcal P$ of $[a, b]$ such that $$U(f, \mathcal P) - L(f, \mathcal P) < \epsilon$$
But I'm not surehow to do that given the two assumptions above.

Comment: Also, a theorem in many books.

Answer (score 2):

Choose $N$ such that $$\|f-f_{N}\|_{\infty}=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)-f_{N}(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3(b-a)}.$$

Next, choose a partition $P$ such that $$U(f_{N},P)-L(f_{N},P)<\frac{\epsilon}{3}.$$

Then,

$$
\begin{aligned}
U(f,P)-L(f,P)&\leq |U(f,P)-U(f_{N},P)|+|U(f_{N},P)-L(f_{N},P)|+|L(f_{N},P)-L(f,P)|\\
&\leq 2\|f-f_{N}\|_{\infty}(b-a)+\frac{\epsilon}{3}\\
&<\frac{2}{3}\epsilon+\frac{\epsilon}{3}\\
&=\epsilon.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Where does that ${1\over 3(b-a)}$ come from in that first line?

Comment: @Dee it is chosen to make the final epsilon look nice. If you just use $\epsilon$ above you would get the bound $U(f,P)- L(f,P) < 3(b-a) \cdot \epsilon$

Comment: Obviously, a duplicAte question.

Comment: Also, a theorem in many books.

Answer (score 0):

We apply the Lebesgue theorem. To check $f$ is continuous a.e. $x\in[a,b]$ we first show the following claim:

If $x=x_0$ is a contuinuous point of $f_n(x)$ for all $n$, then $f(x)$ is also continuous at $x_0$.

In fact, $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\le |f(x)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)|+|f_n(x_0)-f(x)|$. $\forall \epsilon>0$, select $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ s.t. $\forall x\in [a,b]$, $|f(x)-f_n(x)|<\epsilon$, and then select $\delta>0$ s.t. $\forall x\in(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)\cap[a,b]$ we have $|f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)|<\epsilon$ (by the continuity of $f_n$ at $x_0$, such $\delta$ exists. "$\cap[a,b]$ is added to include $x_0\in\{a,b\}$") Then $x\in(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)\cap[a,b]\implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<3\epsilon$, which proves our claim.

Now we conclude
$$\{x\in [a,b]: f\text{ is not continuous at } x_0\}=\cup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+} \{x\in [a,b]: f_n\text{ is not continuous at } x_0\}$$

and hence has measure zero, since the union of countably many sets with measure zero has measure zero.

Furthermore $f$ is bounded. It can be argued as below: $f_n$ is integrable for all $n\implies$ for all $n$, $f_n$ is bounded. By the uniform convergence, select $N$ s.t. $|f(x)-f_N(x)|<1$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Then $|f(x)|\le |f_N(x)|+1$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, i.e. $f$ is bounded.

Comment: Obviously, a duplicAte question.

Comment: Also, a theorem in many books.